# To populate a DataGridView, is it mandatory to use a DataSource?

Tags: .net, winforms, datagridview

I create a DataGridView on a Winform Window through the design screen.  Considering that  My DataGridView control has a column called colName, I do the following:

```
   int counter=0;
   this.dataGridView1.Rows[counter].Cells["colName"].Value = "DI";
   counter++;
   this.dataGridView1.Rows[counter].Cells["colName"].Value = "XI";
   counter++;
```

What happens is that only one column get populated and actually the first value "DI" gets overwritten by XI.

I am wondering is that because I don't have a data source (i.e. dataTable) associated with the DataGridView?

Or am I missing something else?

Please advise.

Comment: For what its worth, I honestly don't use a data source often in `WinForms`, that includes when using `DataGridView`s. Another thing to keep in mind, however, is that a data source can be something as simple as a `List` of items, you don't need to use something as complex as a `DataTable` if it doesn't call for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you don't need to have a data source, but if you aren't doing that, then you need to add rows manually.  Based on your code, it doesn't look like you're adding rows.

Here's what your code might look like:

```
int counter = 0;
this.dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
this.dataGridView1.Rows[counter].Cells["colName"].Value = "DI";
counter++;
this.dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
this.dataGridView1.Rows[counter].Cells["colName"].Value = "XI";
counter++;
```